# case table pivot / pivot multiple column - MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, pivot, case, multiple-columns

I have the below sql data structure and need to pivot it from being a month per row to a column per row.

I understand that pivot can only be done with one columbn but cant quite think of a decent way to use the case statement in order to flip the table.

I want to change from the this:

[image: structure is currently this]

to this:
[image: desired structure]

SQL to create the structure is:

```
create table records (month int,apples int, grapes int, oranges int);

insert into records values (1,1,43,12)
insert into records values (2,23,43,5)
insert into records values (3,32,43,12)
insert into records values (4,23,43,12)
insert into records values (5,23,434,12)
insert into records values (6,23,43,12)
insert into records values (7,33,43,12)
insert into records values (8,23,55,12)
insert into records values (9,23,4332,12)
insert into records values (10,223,43,18)
insert into records values (11,223,43,12)
insert into records values (12,23,143,122)
```

I am not sure how to do this in one statement or by creating additional overhead to server?

can get it right using case statements but requires join statements:

```
select type,sum(jan)jan,sum(feb)feb,sum(mar) mar from ( select 
'apples' type,case when month=1 then apples else 0 end jan
,case when month=2 then apples else 0 end feb
,case when month=3 then apples else 0 end mar
 from #records ) t group by type
 UNION
 select type,sum(jan)jan,sum(feb)feb,sum(mar) mar from ( select 
'oranges' type,case when month=1 then oranges else 0 end jan
,case when month=2 then oranges else 0 end feb
,case when month=3 then oranges else 0 end mar
 from #records ) t group by type
```

I am sure this is not he optimal method, advice welcome.

Thanks in advance as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires combination of both `unpivot` and `pivot`. Try this method

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT month,
               names,
               value
        FROM   Yourtable
               CROSS apply (VALUES ('apples',apples),('grapes',grapes),('oranges',oranges)) tc (names, value)) a
       PIVOT (Max(value)
             FOR month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) pv
```

### [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/BFK30095)

Comment: CROSS apply, I like it.